# One covid vaccine must be stored at -70 degrees Celsius

Tags: vaccination

One covid vaccine must be stored at -70 degrees Celsius. What type of substance or mechanism ensures that the structure of the virus mRNA elements is not distorted at this temperature? And why does this vaccine have to be stored at such a temperature?

Does the vaccine contain a cryoprotectant?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoprotectant

If not why?

Sorry for My English.

Comment: Notably, the ingredients in the covid vaccines have been published.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I know the ingredients of the vaccine. I don't see what causes mRNA to not break down at such a temperature.

Comment: You asked multiple questions and one of them was: `"Does the vaccine contain a cryoprotectant?"` As for why the vaccine must be stored at -70C, that would probably get better answers in Chemistry.SE. It's not really a medical question.

Comment: More or less the same said in the chemistry forum :)

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144734/covid-vaccine-stored-at-70-c

Comment: You actually got a pretty direct answer already in that link, even though it's in a couple of comments. It really has nothing special to do with mRNA or the particular vaccine.

Comment: See also https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96799/need-for-70-degree-temperature-for-corona-vaccine

Comment: Actually they do have cryoprotectant https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25289/why-use-sucrose-rather-than-glucose-in-an-injectable-vaccine/25290

Comment: @Fizz: Your answer seems to be correct.